# exclude file from maven's resource directory

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am using maven for my spring boot application(1.5 version). There are some files in `src/main/resources` like `abc.properties`, `app.json`. Below are some pointer what i want to achieve.

1. Exclude these files getting into the jar.
2. When i run my application through intellij these files should be available in classpath.

I looked at related answers on SO but none matches my case. Any suggestion?

Comment: Why they souldn't be in the jar? In `src/main/resources` should be only resources for the application, that are needed at runtime

Comment: because the content of these files changes and i will have to recreate the jar each time

Comment: When does the file Change?

Comment: put them into another secure folder (not registered as a resource library)

Comment: @Jens it stores the database configuration..when i move to to production...it will have the production database configuration...while development i use the developement db config

Comment: then you should put the files in /src/test/resources or use profiles or best way in my opinion is to put the configuration files outside of the project

Answer (score 2):

you can use the resouce tag in maven pom file:

```
  <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>[your directory]</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>[non-resource file #1]</exclude>
          <exclude>[non-resource file #2]</exclude>
          <exclude>[non-resource file #3]</exclude>
          ...
          <exclude>[non-resource file #n]</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
```

For more informations see: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

Comment: am currently using this but how about the point 2 in my question?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is

1. You want some config file, that is available in classpath during runtime
2. Such config file will be changed based on environment

The way I used to do is:

1. Create a separate directory for such kind of resources, e.g. `src/main/appconfig/`
2. Do NOT include this in POM's resources (i.e. they are not included in resulting JAR)
3. In IDE, add this directory manually as source folder (I usually put this in `testResource` in POM.  When I use Eclipse + M2E, `testResource`s will be added as source folder.  Not sure how IntelliJ though)

For point 2, I used to do it slightly differently. Instead of excluding, I will include in the result JAR but in a separate directory (e.g. appconfig-template), so that people using the application can take this as reference to configure their environment.

An alternative of 3 is: create a separate profile which include `appconfig` as `resource`.  Use this profile only for your IDE setup but not building your artifact.